# Cumulative Mass Function finding probabilities

Tags: probability

[image]

Find the following probabilities:

[image]

The answers to this question:

a) 1, because x < or = 50 covers all random variables assigned probabilities

b) 0.75 make sense to me because X > or eqaul to 40 falls in the 0.75 probability range.

But then, c) 0.25 d) 0.25 e) 0 f) 0 do not make sense to me at all? Anyone care to explain or am I just not understanding this stuff at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function $F$ is defined to be
$$
F(x):=P(X\leq x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
You need two basic properties concerning the CDF to find the wanted probabilities. The first being that
$$
P(X<x)=\lim_{y\,\uparrow x}P(X\leq y)=\lim_{y\,\uparrow x}F(y)
$$
where $y\uparrow x$ means that $y\to x$ while $y<x$. So for instance
$$
P(X<30)=\lim_{y\,\uparrow 30} F(y)=0.25
$$
since $F(y)=0.25$ for all $y$-values sufficiently close to but below $30$. The second property is that
$$
P(X\in A\setminus B)=P(X\in A)-P(X\in B),
$$
whenever $B\subseteq A$. For instance,
$$
P(40\leq X\leq 60)=P(X\in A\setminus B)=P(X\in A)-P(X\in B)
$$
with $A=(-\infty,60]$ and $B=(-\infty,40)$ and hence
$$
\begin{align}
P(40\leq X\leq 60)&=P(X\leq 60)-P(X<40)=F(60)-\lim_{y\,\uparrow 40}F(y)\\
&=1-0.75=0.25.
\end{align}
$$